# Change bootstrap datepicker minViewMode by selection menu

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to change the datepicker's minViewMode by a select menu, which has three selection: Day, Month and Year.

What I have do:

```
$('#timeInterval').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === "Month") {
        $('#datepicker-default .date').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm",
            autoclose: true,
            minViewMode: "months"
        });
    } else if($(this).val() === "Year") {
        $('#datepicker-default .date').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            minViewMode: "years"
        });
    } else {
        $('#datepicker-default .date').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            autoclose: true
        });
    }
});
```

And the selection menu:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="timeInterval" name="timeInterval">
    <option selected="" value="0">Select to choose...</option>
    <option value="Year">Year</option>
    <option value="Month">Month</option>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <option value="Hour">Hour</option>
</select>
```

It now acts that when I choose the selection of the menu, it will initialize right and work good.
But when I try to switch (e.g. from Month to Year), it doesn't work, still work on minViewMode = months (or whatever I first chose).

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it.
Just need to add

```
$('#datepicker-default .date').datepicker("destroy");
```

at first.